# Get all violations for a haveibeenpwned API account

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a Symfony 6 site that uses the have I been pwned API.
I'm trying to send a request to the API but I don't understand why I'm having a structure issue with my request.
https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3#BreachesForAccount
I've attached my code so that you can help me identify the problem.

\src\Controller\BreachDirectoryController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use App\FormType\EmailCheckType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email as EmailConstraint;

class BreachDirectoryController extends AbstractController
{
    private $client;
    private $apiKey;
    private $logger;

    // Constructeur avec injection du client HTTP, de la clé API et du service de log
    public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $client, string $apiKey, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->logger->info('Le contrôleur BreachDirectory a été initialisé.');
    }

    // Route pour la page d'accueil
    #[Route('/', name: 'app_homepage')]
    public function homepage(Request $request): Response
    {
        $this->logger->info('Accès à la page d\'accueil.');

        // Création et gestion du formulaire
        $form = $this->createForm(EmailCheckType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $this->logger->debug('Le formulaire a été géré.');

        // Vérification de la soumission et de la validité du formulaire
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $email = $form->get('email')->getData();
            $this->logger->info("L'email soumis est : {$email}");
        
            // Redirection vers la page de résultats avec l'email encodé dans l'URL
            $url = $this->generateUrl('results', [
                'email_check[email]' => $email,
            ]);

            return $this->redirect($url);
        }

        // Rendu de la page d'accueil avec le formulaire
        return $this->render('breach_directory/homepage.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    // Route pour la page de résultats après vérification de l'email
    #[Route('/results', name: 'results', methods: ["GET"])]
    public function checkEmail(Request $request): Response
    {
        $this->logger->info('Accès à la page de résultats.');

        // Récupération de l'email à partir des données de la requête
        $formData = $request->query->get('email_check');
        dump($formData);
        $email = $formData['email'] ?? null;

        // Si aucun email n'est fourni, on log une alerte
        if (empty($email)) {
            $this->logger->warning("Aucun email fourni pour la vérification.");
            return new Response('Aucun e-mail n\'a été fourni pour vérification.', Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        // Log de l'email en cours de vérification
        $this->logger->info("Vérification de l'email : {$email}");
       
        // Vérification de l'email
        $validator = Validation::createValidator();
        $violations = $validator->validate($email, [new EmailConstraint()]);

        if (0 !== count($violations)) {
            // Si cette condition est vraie, alors il y a un problème de validation.
            // Cela signifie que le message d'erreur de l'email invalide est renvoyé.
            // Vous pourriez ajouter un log ici pour vérifier les violations de validation.
            $this->logger->warning("Erreur de validation : " . $violations[0]->getMessage());
            return new Response('L\'adresse email n\'est pas valide.', Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        // Bloc try pour la gestion de la requête à l'API et des erreurs potentielles
        try {
            // Construction de l'URL pour la requête à l'API
            $url = 'https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3/breachedaccount/' . urlencode($email);
            $this->logger->info("URL de la requête : {$url}");
    
            // Définition des en-têtes de la requête HTTP
            $headers = [
                'hibp-api-key' => $this->apiKey,
                'user-agent' => 'CheckIt',
                // Vous pouvez ajouter d'autres en-têtes si nécessaire
            ];
    
            // Ajouter 'Accept' à la liste des en-têtes
            $headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';

            $this->logger->debug("Requête HTTP : " . json_encode([
                'method' => 'GET',
                'url' => $url,
                'headers' => $headers,
            ]));

            // Juste avant la requête
            $this->logger->debug("En-têtes de la requête : " . json_encode($headers));
            $this->logger->debug("Clé API : " . $this->apiKey);

            // Envoi de la requête HTTP avec les en-têtes
            $response = $this->client->request('GET', $url, [
                'headers' => $headers,
            ]);

            // Log du code de statut de la réponse HTTP
            $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
            $this->logger->info("Code de statut de la réponse : {$statusCode}");

            // Gestion des réponses en fonction du code de statut
            if ($statusCode === 200) {
                $data = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
                return $this->render('breach_directory/results.html.twig', [
                    'email' => $email,
                    'breaches' => $data,
                ]);
            } elseif ($statusCode === 404) {
                return $this->render('breach_directory/results.html.twig', [
                    'email' => $email,
                    'breaches' => [],
                ]);
            } else {
                $this->logger->error("Code de statut inattendu : {$statusCode}");
                return new Response('Une réponse inattendue a été reçue de l\'API Have I Been Pwned.', Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
        } catch (\Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\ClientExceptionInterface $e) {
            $statusCode = $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
            $this->logger->error("ClientException avec le code de statut {$statusCode} : " . $e->getMessage());
            return new Response('Erreur lors de la communication avec l\'API Have I Been Pwned.', Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical("Exception générale : " . $e->getMessage());
            return new Response('Erreur lors de la communication avec l\'API Have I Been Pwned.', Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}

\src\FormType\EmailCheckType.php

<?php
namespace App\FormType;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;

class EmailCheckType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                'label' => 'Adresse e-mail :',
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                ],
            ]);
    }
    
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'constraints' => [
                new Email([
                    'message' => 'L\'adresse email "{{ value }}" n\'est pas valide.',
                ]),
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the exact error raised by Symfony ?

Comment: `".. I don't understand why I'm having a structure issue with my request"` - we do not know what you mean by a `structure issue`

Comment: In my bash console, I enter this request: 
$ curl -H "hibp-api-key:70XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX15" \
> -H "user-agent: MyApp" \
> "https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3/breachedaccount/exemple@gmail.com"
And with this one I get the expected result.
Whereas my Controller I have been pwned returns an error: "Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "400 Bad Request".
Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused."